# Is there any way to do multiple select in primefaces treetable without using the ctrl key

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Is there any way to do multiple select in primeface tree table without using the ctrl key.

Answer (score 0):

You can use checkboxes

```
<p:treeTable ... selectionMode="checkbox" ...>
```

Comment: in selectionMode="multiple" any other way

Comment: @koku Out of the box - no. Maybe with some heavy lifting.

Comment: thank you i handle in js its worked... but i don't no its a correct way

Comment: Hard to tell without looking at the implementation, but test both client side (how it looks) and server side (are selected rows properly maintained) to be sure. You might even look at the PF source code to see how the default behavior is implemented, and check where you could extend it.

Comment: hi i want to know , will primeface jar contains primeface.js file??

Comment: Yes, for `primefaces-5.1.jar` it is located in \META-INF\resources\primefaces\